# How do I create a linear gradient as a JavaScript property value?

Tags: javascript, css, properties, linear-gradients

Is it possible to set a linear gradient as a property value? I only know how to a hex value to the property, but how would you do the gradient equivalent of a CSS value in a JavaScript property value?

CSS

```
background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FAF9FA 0%, #F2F5FE 65.75%);
```

JavaScript to add a gradient to the background property.

```
this.opts = {
  background: 0x000000,
  fill: 0xffffff,
  ...options,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to implement it like this?

```
this.opts = {
  background: 'linear-gradient(180deg, #FAF9FA 0%, #F2F5FE 65.75%)',
  ...options,
};
```